# $.getJSON() call is extremely delayed in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, google-chrome, getjson

Below I have attached a snippet of my client-side javascript/Jquery code which does POST/GET calls in sequence. In the Firefox browser both the calls take less than 500ms, and return immediately from my locally running NodeJS server.

But when the same sequence is run via the Chrome browser, getJSON() call takes about 25 seconds and is absolutely not right. When debugging locally, I find that the getJSON() call takes about 24 seconds to reach my GET route on the locally running NodeJS webserver.

Could this be a Chrome browser-related bug? Or Is it a Bug in JQuery? I cannot seem to get my head around this snippet of code.

Any help regarding this would be invaluable.

```
        const token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
        const data = { root: 'xyz'};
        $.ajaxSetup({ headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),'content-type': 'application/json'}});
        $.post(`/api/settings/`, JSON.stringify(data), (res)=>{
            $.getJSON('/api/projects/', (_all_protocols) => {
                console.log(_all_protocols);
            });
        });
```

Comment: Get the url for the getJSON call and pop it into a chrome tab url, and see how long it takes to return.

Comment: A direct call via the url is instantaneous...

Comment: How large is the response?

Comment: Miniscule response. Actually the request itself is taking time. It takes about 24 seconds for this call to reach the server route handler.

Comment: With just the browser, or with jQuery, or how?

Comment: With jQuery -> 24 seconds. On the browser its instantaneous... (Chrome only)

Comment: So, with jQuery performing the ajax call, open your network console and find the ajax request and inspect the time graph.  See how much time was spent sending the request, getting the response, and such

Comment: The funny part is if I set up breakpoints, or open the developer console on chrome then this Jquery call does not cause problems. It's fast.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/a2PqCgU.png  What is the time breakdown of your xhr request when made with jQuery?

Comment: This is what it looks like. But mind you, when my dev console is open even this Jquery call is fast.   https://gyazo.com/50bf3997ada9876561e28e8b31d565a5  So I am not sure how can I get this same graph without opening dev console. maybe a 3rd party tool ?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure why there is a time difference depending upon the visibility of the console.  Definitely sounds more like something with the browser, rather than something specific to jQuery.

Comment: Exactly, this seems like some browser specific issue. Probably a different thread blocks the jquery call in some way.